Angular child component removed from router-outlet if navigating again to parent path
I have an Angular component that displays one or another child component through a <router-outlet> according to a condition.
When initially the page loads with the path /orders, the parent component OrderComponent evaluates the condition in its ngOnInit() and navigates to the relative child route. The target component is rendered correctly.
However, by clicking on a link that points to the same parent route (/orders) the content in the <router-outlet> disappears, while I would expect that the content would remain intact. Of course, any of the ngOnInit() is not called, as the path is the same and the component (parent and child is not reloaded). I do not understand though what makes the child's content disappear. Removing the option { skipLocationChange: true } also does not bring any improvement.
Parent template
<h1> content </h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Parent ngOnit
ngOnInit() {
  this.orderService.isOrderEligible()
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe((isOrderEligible: boolean) => {
    // According to the condition the target child route/component is loaded
    if (!isOrderEligible) {
      this.route.navigate(['orders/public-products'], { skipLocationChange: true } );
    } else {
      this.route.navigate(['orders/store-products'], { skipLocationChange: true });
    }
  });

}
Module Routes
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OrdersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'public-products',
        loadChildren: () => import('../orders/public-orders.module').then((m) => m.PublicOrderModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'store-products',
        loadChildren: () => import('../orders/store-orders.module').then((m) => m.StoreOrderModule),
      },
   ]
}


"I do not understand though what makes the child's content disappear". The child content will only appear when the route matches its configured path.  If the path changes and doesn't match, then of course the child component will not be rendered.

The path matches as it is the same as at the beginning: the initial path is "root/orders" --> parent component loads and according to condition navigates to the child path (e.g. "root/orders/public-products"). Now if I click a link pointing to "root/orders", the content of the  in the parent's template disappears. The path changed, but it is still a valid (the initial) one.

Does this StackBlitz demonstrate your scenario?

Yes, the final result is the same and now it is obvious why the child component is removed from the parent. Since there is not a default redirect/fallback to any child in case the parent route is selected. So simple (now) :) If you write an answer, I would gladly accept it. Thanks


"I do not understand though what makes the child's content disappear".

The child content will only appear when the route matches its configured path. If the path changes and no longer matches a configured route, then no child component will be rendered.
Here is a StackBlitz demo that might help illustrate the issue.

Thanks for the answer. I think it would be beneficial for others to read in the future, to mention the possibility of having a default redirect as I suggested in my last comment. This way even if the parent (valid) path is matched, still the child content (the default one) would be displayed instead of a blank page.
